# .htaccess: Replace part of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, replace

I've got some duplicate content and want to redirect to the right url (remove a part of the url and redirect)

Examples:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/url/1-url
http://www.domain.com/es/url/1-url
http://www.domain.com/fr/url/1-url
....
```

The individually should redirected to:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/url
http://www.domain.com/es/url
http://www.domain.com/fr/url
....
```

Because I have to do this for a lot of urls, I can't redirect them each manually and need a rule which detects if the url contains "/1-url" and if yes remove this part from the url - but only this part.

Would be great if a mod-rewrite hero can help me with this. I'm searching for solution over .htaccess via a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
RewriteRule (\w{2})/([^/]+)/\d+-[^/]+$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/\d+-[^/]+$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a possibility to replace the "1" with any number. This rule should be valid for every url with a number like "1-", "234-", "1123-" and so on?

Comment: Then it would be perfect :)

Comment: Sorry to add this too, but is it possible to get it to work with "http://www.domain.com/url/1-url" (redirect to http://www.domain.com/url) too or is here a seperate rewrite rule needed? I think it would be the easiest solution if it possible to cut of the "/[Any Number]-[Something]" part everytime away and define the first "url" part to have a little bit "security" to not replace the wrong urls. Then it would work for http://www.domain.com/url/1-url and http://www.domain.com/en/url/1-url.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a imported file to each 1-url page only add redirect method to imported file.

For example your every 1-url page have header.php, add redirect function to header.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my details aren't exact as I needed. It's a problem with Joomla and I don't want to edit files. I'm sure there is a rewrite rule, which is able to cut the needed part out of it. Otherwise I've to redirect > 200 urls manually. It's my site structure where I want to remove duplicate content. I don't import anything.